# Can I move to mortgaged property when rolling 'Mr Monopoly' on Speed Die

Tags: monopoly-mega-edition

If I roll Mr. Monopoly on the speed die, and all the properties have been bought, according to the rules I have to move to the next place that I have to pay rent.
What is the rule, if the next place I would have to pay rent happens to be mortgaged - and I do not therefore have to pay rent. Do I have to go to a non mortgaged property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rules [here](https://winning-moves.com/images/megamonopolyrules.pdf)

From mortgaged properties rules.

> If the property is mortgaged, no rent can be collected.

From the speed dice rules -

> If you roll a Mr. Monopoly after all of the properties are owned, make
>   a normal move according to the white dice, then move ahead to the
>   first property on which you need to pay rent. If all other players
>   properties are mortgaged, stay where you are.

Together, these rules mean that the first property on which you need to pay rent cannot be a mortgaged property.  You must therefore move to the next non-mortgaged property owned by another player, in order to pay rent.  The rules also clarify that you don't move if all other players' owned properties are mortgaged, which is further evidence that you cannot move to a mortgaged property when you roll Mr. Monopoly.